# Visual SVN does not see files added to Angular project

Tags: angular, svn, visual-studio-2022, visualsvn

I am using VisualSVN with Visual Studio 2022.
Everything works great for normal projects, but one of my projects is an Angular project.
For that project, none of the files are highlighted with any kind of status icon. Additionally, when I add new files via CLI commands (e.g, "ng g c new-component"), or manually via the Visual Studio "Add => New Item" option, none of the newly added files are present when I do an SVN check-in, unless I click "Show unversioned files", which allows me to select the newly added files.

For every other project type, the status icons show as expected, and when I add a file to the solution it is automatically shown for check-in when I do a commit.

I note that the project file ends with ".esproj", rather than ".proj". Could that be related?

Anyway, I'd love to see a solution.

Thanks in advance.